# Can reduced dynamics lead to a map that is not completely positive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/729481/how-can-an-entangled-initial-state-lead-to-non-positive-reduced-dynamics).

The setup is the same as in that question. We consider a map from a certain set of density operators $\rho_S$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_S$ to the complete set of density operators on that $\mathcal{H}_S$ that is a composition of:

1. An "assignment map" $\Phi$ from some set of density operators $\rho_S$ on $\mathcal{H}_S$ to the set of density operators on a larger Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_R$. (For the purpose of this question, we require that the assignment map's image consist of actual density operators (i.e. positive semidefinite and trace-1 Hermitian operators - the paper linked from the previous question does not make this requirement), and that it be consistent in the sense defined in the previous question, but we do not require that the map be linear or defined on the whole space of density operators on $\mathcal{H}_S$.)
2. Unitary time evolution on the enlarged Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_R$ with some unitary operator $U$.
3. The partial trace over $\mathcal{H}_R$.

That is:
$$\rho_S \to \rho_S' = \mathrm{Tr}_R[U \Phi(\rho_S) U^\dagger]. \tag{1}$$

It is known that if the assignment map $\Phi$ is a product map (in the sense defined in the previous question) $\Phi(\rho_S) \equiv \rho_S \otimes \rho_R$, then the composed map (1) must be completely positive and trace-preserving (CPTP).

As discussed in the previous question, in general - whether or not the assignment map is a product map - since we require that the output of the assignment map be a density operator, the inputs and outputs of this composed map (1) must all be density operators, so the composed map is (trivially) positive and trace-preserving, since all possible inputs and outputs are positive semidefinite and trace-1.

But if the assignment map is consistent but not a product map, then does the composed map (1) need to be *completely* positive?

Comment: I'm a bit confused tbh. You defined "consistent" in the previous question as $\Phi$ st ${\rm Tr}_R\Phi(\rho)=\rho$ for all $\rho$, which implies $\Phi(\rho)=\rho\otimes\sigma$ for some $\sigma$. But the propreties of such maps are quite trivial: if $\sigma$ is a state, then $\Phi$ is CPTP. If $\sigma$ has unit trace, then $\Phi$ is trace-preserving, if $\sigma\ge0$ then $\Phi$ is CP, etc. So how can a map be consistent and *not* a product map? Or are you asking how to prove that "consistent" implies it being a product map?

Comment: @glS No, consistency alone does not require that the assignment map $\Phi$ be a product map. Equation (1) of https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.1060 gives an explicit example of an assignment map that's consistent but generically outputs an entangled state.

Comment: @glS Another way to see this is to count degrees of freedom: if $\mathcal{H}_S$ and $\mathcal{H}_R$ have dimensions $N_S$ and $N_R$ respectively, then the set of states $\rho_{SR}$ on $\mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_R$ has $(N_S N_R)^2 - 1$ real parameters, and fixing $\mathrm{Tr}_R[\rho_{SR}]$ imposes $N_S^2 - 1$ constraints, leaving $N_S^2 (N_R^2 - 1)$ remaining real degrees of freedom for $\rho_{RS}$ even after fixing its partial trace - and these are independent for each choice of input $\rho_S$, for a total of $(N_S^2 - 1) N_S^2 (N_R^2 - 1)$ real degrees of freedom for the entire map..

Comment: ...  Whereas a product map only has $N_R^2 - 1$ real degrees of freedom, which specify the state $\sigma$.

Comment: @glS For example, consider an assignment map that maps the maximally mixed state for a single qubit to a pure Bell state. Such a map is consistent (at least for this particular input), but it certainly isn't a product map.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Which equation are you referring to in the linked paper? The first equation in the text is a map sending qubits to qubits, so how does it relate to the issue at hand? Surely $\Phi$ here sends states in $\mathcal H_S$ into states in $\mathcal H_S\otimes\mathcal H_R$, so the output dimension is larger than the input one. I also don't get your example: a map sending a maximally mixed state into whatever is one whose input space is $\mathcal H_S\otimes\mathcal H_R$, so that's also different than the kind of map $\Phi$ is here

Comment: in other words, the only way to make sense of the condition ${\rm Tr}_R\Phi(\rho_S)=\rho_S$ is to have $\Phi$ map states in $\mathcal H_S$ into states in $\mathcal H_S\otimes\mathcal H_R$. But then you seem to be considering maps with different input/output spaces, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @glS Yes, the assignment map $\Phi$ maps density operators on $\mathcal{H}_S$ to density operators on $\mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_R$, which is indeed a larger Hilbert space than $\mathcal{H}_S$. The equation that I'm referring to in the PRL paper is, as I said, the equation labeled (1), at the bottom-left of pg. 1061 (not the first unnumbered equation in the paper). Yes, the output space of $\Phi$ is always larger than the input space.

Comment: @glS I don't know what you mean when you imply that the maximally mixed state lives on $\mathcal{H}_S \otimes \mathcal{H}_R$. I'm not talking about a maximally *entangled* state, but the maximally *mixed* state, which lives on $\mathcal{H}_S$ alone. Explicitly, the maximally mixed state for a single qubit is just $\left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} \end{array} \right)$.

Comment: yes, sorry, I misread about the maximally mixed state. Still, the only map sending that to a given pure state $|\psi\rangle$ is the replacement map $\Phi(\rho)={\rm Tr}(\rho) |\psi\rangle\!\langle \psi|$ (you see it eg via convexity arguments). And so yes, your example works for that particular input, but doesn't work for any other input, so it's still not "consistent" according to the definition.

Comment: @glS That is completely untrue for an unrestricted map. Convexity is irrelevant unless you assume linearity. Your claim is true assuming the three assumptions above, but the entire point of the question is to rigorously understand exactly which assumptions need to be assumed on the map $\Phi$ in order to derive the CPTP property. Even if you *do* assume linearity, then there are consistent non-product maps with entangled outputs, as given in the example in the paper.

Comment: ah, sure, if you don't assume linearity then most basic results don't apply. I would stress explicitly that you don't require linearity in the question then though, because the term "quantum map" is usually used to refer to linear functions between linear operators, and people in this context almost always consider linear maps, hence why I was implicitly assuming that (I see now that it is mentioned in the question, but I would give it more prominence as that parenthetical remark is easy to miss). I would not call this a "map", but rather a more generic "function" between states

Comment: @glS Thank you for the feedback. But I never use the term "quantum map" in my question, and I think it's pretty standard terminology that the term "map" by itself just means "function", with no implication of linearity. But in any case, the question remains nontrivial even if we do only consider consistent linear maps. The example given in the PRL article is both consistent and linear, but it isn't a product map, and it isn't clear to me whether the resulting time evolution is described by a completely positive map.